# Hide Sheets from a List Containing the Sheet names?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to hide sheets from a list containing the respective name sheets.
I will have a Filter function, each time i open the file I want the Hidden sheets updated.

I have this, but this is fixed values or fixed names.. and i need to write 30 variables...

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var inicio = ss.getSheetByName("INICIO");
var lasanhavegetariana = ss.getSheetByName("LasanhaVegetariana");
var arrozdepato = ss.getSheetByName("ArrozDePato");
var bacalhau = ss.getSheetByName("Bacalhau");

var iniciocell1 = inicio.getRange('C2');
var iniciocell2 = inicio.getRange('C3');
var iniciocell3 = inicio.getRange('C4');

if (iniciocell1.getValue() == 0) {lasanhavegetariana.hideSheet();}
if (iniciocell1.getValue() == 1) {lasanhavegetariana.showSheet();}

if (iniciocell2.getValue() == 0) {arrozdepato.hideSheet();}
if (iniciocell2.getValue() == 1) {arrozdepato.showSheet();}

if (iniciocell3.getValue() == 0) {bacalhau.hideSheet();}
if (iniciocell3.getValue() == 1) {bacalhau.showSheet();}

}
```

How do i write a function that hide sheets from a range A1:A20??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, it would be better to grab the whole range and then iterate from there instead of create a new variable for each sheet.

If you have the the list of sheet names in column 'A' and the flag value in column 'B' (i know you have it in C  i just change it to make it easier), you can iterate each row, get the name of the sheet and the flag value and just call the function getSheetByName and then, depending on the flag value, hideSheet or showSheet.

```
     function hide()
    {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var row =ss.getLastRow();
      var col =ss.getLastColumn();
      var range = ss.getSheetByName('INICIO').getRange(1,1,row,col).getValues();

      for(var i =1; i<range.length; i++)
      {
        var name = range[i][0]; // get the value in column A
        var flag = range[i][1]; // get the value in column B

        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name); //It would be better to validate if the function returned a value 
//so the code won't stop if it cannot find the sheet.
        if(flag == 0)
        {
          sheet.hideSheet();
        }
        else
        {
          sheet.showSheet();
        }
      }
    }
```

Make sure the names of the sheets are correct so the function can find them. Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm getting this error (TypeError: Cannot call method "hideSheet" of null.), if i have other values in column C or D. and if the script dont find the sheet name, it stop working and dont hide next sheets..

Comment: The function getSheetByName() will return an empty (null) object if it cannot find the sheet. That's why I commented in the code that you should validate the variable "var sheet" after calling getSheetByName in case it doesn't find the sheet to avoid the script to stop working.  In your example, you mentioned getting the info from A and C, why would it fail from having other info in D? are you getting now the info from columns C and D?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the data as a range and based upon those values you can hide the required sheets.
To hide sheets on the opening of the spreadsheet, use the `hideSheets()` in the `onOpen()`.

This also checks the condition if you don't have those many sheets as specified by flags in the fixed data range `A1:A10`.

```
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Hide Sheets')
  .addItem('Hide Sheets', 'hideSheets')
  .addItem('Show All Sheets', 'showAllSheets')
  .addToUi();
}

function hideSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var configSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetValues = configSheet.getRange('A1:A10').getValues();
  Logger.log(sheetValues);
  for(var i=0;i<sheetValues.length;i++){
    if(ss.getSheets()[i]!=undefined){
      if(sheetValues[i]==0){
        ss.getSheets()[i].hideSheet();
      }else{
        ss.getSheets()[i].showSheet();
      }
    }
  }
}

function showAllSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i=0;i<ss.getSheets().length;i++)
    ss.getSheets()[i].showSheet();
}
```

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cohq2d_4EjTxFod2yczt_bbkrwhHeo5S87zDwyVRGnI/edit?usp=sharing) spreadsheet with the above functionality.

Comment: i'm getting this error  (TypeError: Cannot call method "hideSheet" of null.), if i have other values in column C or D.